# Loop through element of type chart in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to loop through all elements of type ".dxpc-content img" if it contains a chart... I then want to call the PerformCallback method on the chart by retrieving it's attribute "id" with the following:

I am trying this like so:

```
$('.dxpc-content img').each(
    function () {
        if ($(this).attr("id").attr("id")) {
            alert("contains chart");

            if ($(this) && $(this).attr('id').attr('id') && window[$(this).attr('id').attr('id')].PerformCallback) {
                window[$(this).attr('id').attr('id')].PerformCallback("stat" + "," + brokerStats);
            }
        }

    }
```

If I inspect the element in Chrome dev tools it looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have chart with `ids starting with barChart`... which could be seen in image attached so you need to find the elements `having ids containing barChart`,

```
$('.dxpc-content img').each(
    function () {
        if ($(this).attr("id").indexOf('barChart') != -1) {
            alert("contains chart");

            if ($(this) && $(this).attr('id').attr('id') && window[$(this).attr('id').attr('id')].PerformCallback) {
                window[$(this).attr('id').attr('id')].PerformCallback("stat" + "," + brokerStats);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Im testing this now, but the alert never gets hit.

Comment: My fault, I had the function that calls this method commented. I am now inside the if, and the alert gets called. However the PerformCallback is not called. I think I might not be at correct child level. Is there an easy way to determine the child level?